# Show the values inside bullets of AmChart's line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I made a line chart with amCharts and I want to show the values inside the bullets, is that possible?

Here is the chart that I used : [link](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-chart-with-scroll-and-zoom/#theme-light)

Comment: I don't think this is possible without getting deep into the sources... Sorry

Comment: thanks anyways, is there any other charting library that allows that ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. However not out of the box by default. Having a quick look at the code you would need to alter the: scale(1) to something larger depending on how much text you are trying to put in there.

Setting a scale of 20 for example instead of 1.

You would then need to add to the current js code and create a content area and again assign a id to each so it inserts a [value].

It would not be a simple task if you are not fluent with js.

i am unable to help you any more then that.

Comment: the second part concerning the js code is not clear, thanks anyways